# Typo3 $this->cObj->enableFields() SQL error WHERE AND

Tags: php, mysql, typo3

Im using this line to do a DB select:

```
$res = $TYPO3_DB->exec_SELECTquery('*', $table, $this->cObj->enableFields($table), '' , '', '');
```

The problem is an SQL error:

SELECT * FROM xyz **WHERE AND** xyz.deleted=0 AND.......

Someone knows why this happens? Is there something wrong how I handle the where clouse with enableFields function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TYPO3 wiki](http://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Developers_Guide)

> If you don't already have a WHERE clause, you will get a wrong SQL
>   statement ("SELECT * FROM tt_address WHERE AND ..."), so you have to
>   strip the leading AND

Use `'1'.$this->cObj->enableFields($table)`